# PyQt5 changing images

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a player for a custom file in PyQT5 and I have a set of images that I want to render in a PyQt widget one after another so I can play it as a continious video. So my question is how can I do something like that? Some code example or a guide would be great. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

```
class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.pixmap = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene.addItem(self.pixmap)
        self.initUI().graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        graphicsView = QGraphicsView()   

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your widget, you can add a QGraphicsVew, add a QGraphicsScene to the graphicsview, add a pixmap to the scene and continuously change the pixmap through setPixmap() function.

So in the constructor of your widget, add these (it is assumed that your .ui file has a QGraphicsView called graphicsView):

```
self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
self.pixmap = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
self.scene.addItem(self.pixmap)
self.ui.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
```

In your player function, which is called periodically, you set the pixmap:

```
self.t1_pixmap.setPixmap(img)
```

where `img` contains the pixmap loaded from your image files.

---

**Update (based on the code given, and a correction):**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self)
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.pixmap = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        scene.addItem(self.pixmap)
        graphicsView.setScene(scene)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        graphicsView.resize(300,200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()

    def play(self):
        img = QtGui.QPixmap('D:\\tmp\\image.png')
        self.pixmap.setPixmap(img)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    window.play()
    app.exec()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by .ui? I'm using initUI method to initialize GUI. I've edited post added code.

Comment: OK. If you use QtDesigner tool, then you can save the resulting .ui file and load into PyQt5. But your method of doing it programmatically is also fine. You need to add `graphicsView` to your mainwindow somewhere though.